# Weird space between container and navbar

Tags: html, css, whitespace, containers, navbar

Okay weirdest thing is happening I separated my navbar from my container and now there is a space when there should be none, i tried everything setting div margins and padding, I want it to be clean without having to use a negative margin, any help greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
 <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Test</title>
   <link href="body.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="navbar1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
       <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
         <li>black</li>
         <li>blue</li>
         <li>green</li>
         <li>yellow</li>
         <li>haha</li>
         <li>good</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- End of navbar -->
    <div id="container">
    <div class="logo">
            <img src="" alt="sun" />
    </div><!-- End of logo -->

    <div id="header1">
            <span>Hello World</span>
    </div><!-- End of header -->

    <div class="logo">
            <img src="" alt="sun" />
    </div><!-- End of logo -->
    <div id="p1">
            <p> up </p>
    </div><!-- End of p1 -->
        </div><!-- End of container -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
#navbar /* navbar container */
{
    background-color:#999;
    border-bottom:solid 3px #333;
    margin:0px;
}
#navbar ul /* unordered lists withinin navbar container */
{
    width:1000px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#9900FF;

}

#navbar li /* list items within navbar container */
{
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    display:inline;
    border-right:solid 2px #33FFFF;
    border-left:solid 2px #33FFFF;
}
```

CSS #2

```
body /* this is to set the body element, but mostly used for removing margins. */
{
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#666666;
}

#container /* this is our overall content container. */
{
    width:1000px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    border-left:groove 5px #444;
    border-right:groove 5px #444;
    border-bottom:groove 5px #444;
}

.logo img /* this is logo on the right side. */
{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;

}

#header1 /* This is the header directly between the logos */
{
    height:96px;
    width:592px;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:48px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    alignment-baseline:middle;
    border-left:dashed 4px #00F;
    border-right:dashed 4px #00F;
    border-bottom:dashed 4px #00F;
}
```

Comment: this might help; if you put a border around the container or the logo; the space disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's simple. you need need something like a "reset.css"...that sets all the default css as it should be...but this will be a simple fix for now:

```
*
{
   margin:  0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS and you should be fine:

```
#p1 p {
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SbVXt/)**. The default margins on the paragraph tag in your p1 div are the cause.

Comment: mucho gracias! dunno where my mind is today not realizing i hadn't tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code please check :-

HTML

```
    <title>Test</title>
   <link href="body.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="navbar1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
       <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
         <li>black</li>
         <li>blue</li>
         <li>green</li>
         <li>yellow</li>
         <li>haha</li>
         <li>good</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- End of navbar -->
    <div id="container">
    <div class="logo">
            <img src="" alt="sun" />
    </div><!-- End of logo -->

    <div id="header1">
            <span>Hello World</span>
    </div><!-- End of header -->

    <div class="logo">
            <img src="" alt="sun" />
    </div><!-- End of logo -->
    <div id="p1">
            <p> up </p>
    </div><!-- End of p1 -->
        </div><!-- End of container -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
body /* this is to set the body element, but mostly used for removing margins. */
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#666666;
}

#navbar /* navbar container */
{
    background-color:#999;
    border-bottom:solid 3px #333;
    margin:0px;
}
#navbar ul /* unordered lists withinin navbar container */
{
    width:1000px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#9900FF;

}

#navbar li /* list items within navbar container */
{
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    display:inline;
    border-right:solid 2px #33FFFF;
    border-left:solid 2px #33FFFF;
}

#container /* this is our overall content container. */
{
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    border-left:groove 5px #444;
    border-right:groove 5px #444;
    border-bottom:groove 5px #444;
}

.logo img /* this is logo on the right side. */
{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;

}

#header1 /* This is the header directly between the logos */
{
    height:96px;
    width:592px;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:48px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    alignment-baseline:middle;
    border-left:dashed 4px #00F;
    border-right:dashed 4px #00F;
    border-bottom:dashed 4px #00F;
}
```

i have added margin padding:0; in your css and you can use reset.css so that will save your default extra margin paddings....

see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/6xuSp/35/